# How to use Application/Assembly properties

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, configuration-files

I'm writing a two-project solution with a class library designed for re-use, and an application which will consume said class library.  The library has a Properties file which is needed both in the library itself and in the application.  Unfortunately when I tried to implement this the "obvious" way, by keeping the properties in the Class library and accessing it from the application by fully specifying `LibraryName.Properties...`, it failed (which only goes to show that instinct is a poor substitute for knowledge).

I'm getting the following error:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled
  Message=Configuration system failed to initialize
  Source=System.Configuration
  BareMessage=Configuration system failed to initialize
  Line=0
  StackTrace:
       at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
       at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
       at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
       at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.GetConfigSection()
       at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()
       at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_IndentSize()
       at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.InitializeSettings()
       at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.get_Listeners()
  InnerException: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
   Message=Unrecognized configuration section userSettings. (C:\Users\CPFOHL\AppData\Local\CompanyName\ProductName.vshost.exe_Url_irhjcfvtmdm11v2ub0re3en5hgllqjz4\10.0.0.0\user.config line 3)
   Source=System.Configuration
   BareMessage=Unrecognized configuration section userSettings.
   Filename=C:\Users\CPFOHL\AppData\Local\CompanyName\ProductName.vshost.exe_Url_irhjcfvtmdm11v2ub0re3en5hgllqjz4\10.0.0.0\user.config
   Line=3
   StackTrace:
        at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
        at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
        at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
        at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(Object sender, InternalConfigEventArgs e)
   InnerException:
```

The only other information I can think to share is that I have the two projects in separate solutions, and I added the Library with "Add Existing," but that doesn't feel like the error...

I'm sure there's an easy answer, let me know if I can post any extra information.

---

**[EDIT]**
I'm pretty sure that the Settings are configured correctly.  The worked until I moved them to a separate solution.  I then moved them back in and have been regretting it since...  When I click Synchronize in the Settings editor I get the following:

```
No user.config files were found in any of the following locations:
```

It then lists all the places it looked (mostly in User/CPFOHL/AppData).  I hope that helps.

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean. Have you wrote a class library that is supposed to be used by more projects? (Even outside your solution? (Like a plug-in framework?))

Comment: Config file is per executable (exe), not per library (dll).  Hope this helps.

Comment: That *could* help.  It's what I want, but I still want the Properties to work. At all.  It's crashing right now.

Comment: Are you sure your config file is ok? It appears it has problems with the "userSettings" section. If you have a custom configuration section it has to be configured correctly. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't seem to exist anywhere that VS2010 knows to look for it. When I click Synchronize it yells at me for now having the correct files...let's see if I can fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try deleting `C:\Users\CPFOHL\AppData\Local\CompanyName\ProductName.vshost.exe_Url_irhjcfvtmdm11v2ub0re3en5hgllqjz4\10.0.0.0\user.config`

Perhaps you changed the type on one of the properties and an old one was already persisted to the per user store.

Comment: As soon as I get in to work (or if I can find the remote desktop instructions for my company online) I'll give this a try! Thanks so much for the suggestion.

Comment: 1000 kisses upon your feet. (Ok, so maybe I'm not quite *that* excited, but thank you so much).  It regenerated what I needed.  I can't believe I didn't think to delete it...